# When do I create a new team project in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, team-project

We are setting up TFS 2010 and we have about 15 different applications we would like to migrate to TFS. We have already decided that we will do 1 collection. The question I have is should we create multiple team projects for each of our applications or should we put all of our applications under one team project? What are the advantages/disadvantages we would face with those scenarios for work items, builds, etc?

Comment: NB. this could equally be stated as "When do I create a new GIT/Mecurial/... repository?".

Comment: @Richard: I disagree - a TFS Team Project doesn't map well to a git (for example) repo.  A Team Project designates a workflow (a process template) and usually contains multiple applications or projects.  That is to say that typically a Team Project is a higher level of what would map to a git repo, and contains many of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bar for what should be in a team project is whether the applications and/or people working on the applciations have shared resources, like the work items.

In the upcoming TFS11 there is the notion of backlogs (if you haven't seen it yet, I recommend to go to the [\BUILD\ recordings](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-793T)). If your applications share the sprints or backlogs, then I would create one team project (or a team project per pool of applications that share these).

If the applications are developed seperately and you want to use different processes, then use multiple team projects.

Answer (score -1):

I saw a good post by one of the TFS ALM Rangers on this recently which goes over all the major disadvantages of splitting into multiple team projects.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2010/11/12/good-reasons-to-not-create-a-new-team-project.aspx

However as Ewald points out the new Sprint, Backlog and Team support in TFS11 are actually fairly good reasons to split your projects out.

Comment: Looks like addition a teams to team projects i  tfs11 means multiple backlogs per team project

Comment: The multiple backlogs per team project feature works really nicely so I stand by my view of only having one team project to reduce upgrade friction